# Create App Service in Azure from Visual Studio 2017 stuck on Deploying step 1

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-functions

I have an existing Azure Function App that was previously deployed to a different tenant/subscription. I have deleted the profile, and created a new profile to point it to a new subscription. I have created the profile via Visual Studio and am now trying to publish. The screen just sits on the below, and never progresses. There's no other feedback or logs to review to understand why this is happening. Any ideas? Connectivity isn't an issue as the resource groups available etc load into the dialog window, indicating that visual studio can 'see' them.

Comment: How long it takes you? because at some point it make sense creating resource takes some time.

Comment: Also if you go to portal do you see created resources?

Comment: BTW. I would recommend you to re-upload screenshot with blurred credentials

Comment: Picture removed temporarily. There are no created resources in the portal, and I've waited 15 minutes. Far more than should be required.

Comment: Have you restarted vs and tried again?

Comment: Yes, and restarted my machine entirely.

Comment: Have you tried signing Visual Studio out of Azure and back in again?